# Android Project on Maps

Tags: android, apk

How to run Android Project(apk file) on user Device without running it on Emulator.i was trying to run my android project directly on the device..please help me with it.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/running-app.html

Answer (score 0):

Try use **adb** Tool of android

```
http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html
```

Try this command

```
adb -d install YOUR_APP.apk
```